python stats.spearmanr and R cor.test(method='spearman') don't return the same p-value?
I am trying to calculate spearman's rho value for some data in both Python and R but I get different P-value results, what am I doing wrong with python?
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

data = np.array([
    [27,30],
    [18,12],
    [9,11],
    [6,10],
    [31,32],
    [19,13],
    [20,31]
])
stats.spearmanr(data[:,0], data[:,1],alternative='two-sided')
# SignificanceResult(statistic=0.9642857142857145, pvalue=0.0004541491691941689)

cor.test(x=c(27,18,9,6,31,19,20), y=c(30,12,11,10,32,13,31), method='spearman')
#   Spearman's rank correlation rho
#
# data:  c(27, 18, 9, 6, 31, 19, 20) and c(30, 12, 11, 10, 32, 13, 31)
# S = 2, p-value = 0.002778
# alternative hypothesis: true rho is not equal to 0
# sample estimates:
#      rho 
# 0.9642857 


If you add a exact=F parameter to cor.test, you'll get the same p-value. Note that if you read the scipy documentation, they advise using a permutation test if you have a small sample size: "Although calculation of the p-value does not make strong assumptions about the distributions underlying the samples, it is only accurate for very large samples (>500 observations). For smaller sample sizes, consider a permutation test (see Examples section below).".

The help page in R and the source code in Scipy provide the details.  The former uses an exact calculation in your example while the latter is an approximation that for small datasets is likely a bad one (based on a Student t distribution).  To employ the Scipy approximation in R, include , exact = FALSE in your call to cor.test.
> cor.test(x=c(27,18,9,6,31,19,20), y=c(30,12,11,10,32,13,31), 
  method='spearman', exact = FALSE)


  Spearman's rank correlation rho

data:  c(27, 18, 9, 6, 31, 19, 20) and c(30, 12, 11, 10, 32, 13, 31)
S = 2, p-value = 0.0004541
alternative hypothesis: true rho is not equal to 0
sample estimates:
      rho 
0.9642857


This reproduces the Scipy p-value of $0.0004541$ to the full precision shown.  Internally, it equals $0.0004541491691941\,6$ which differs from the Scipy output in the 17th decimal place.  That likely arises from an inconsequential difference in the underlying algorithms (or precision targets) for computing quantiles of Student t distributions.
